# DRY view components in Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, render, block, dry

I want to create abstract components for my views, that don't disclose the way they will be rendered.
The example is an tabbed nav box like the [tabs from bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

In my view I want to write s.th. like:

```
    = tab_section(self) do
      - tab 'tab1' do
        %p tab1 content
        = link_to example_var, "#top"
      - tab 'tab2' do
        %p tab2 content
        = link_to 'http://example.com', "#top"
```

which should then be rendered to s.th. like this:

```
        <ul>
          <li>tab1</li>
          <li>tab2</li>
        </ul>
        <div class='content'>
          <div class='tab'>
            <p>tab1 content</p>
            <a href='#top'>this could also be an @var from the controller</a>
          </div>
          <div class='tab'>
            <p>tab2 content</p>
            <a href='#top'>http://example.com</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

All my attempts to defer rendering of the tab 'content' failed. I created a [minimal rails app](https://github.com/axelerator/rails_components) demonstrating the three approaches I  took.

Take a look at the application_helper.rb and the welcome#show view.
What is the correct way to do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

I got some support and found the following solution:

The outer 'component' must be passed into the block to call the inner function upon:

```
      = tab_section2 do |section|
        - section.tab 'tab1' do
          %p tab1 content
          = link_to example_var, "#top"
        - section.tab 'tab2' do
          %p tab2 content
          = link_to 'http://example.com', "#top"
```

Since we don't need to bind the block to the tab_section instance (previously done with instance_exec), we can yield the block directly.

```
      def tab_section2(&blk)
        raise "Y U NO SUPPLY block?" unless block_given?
        ts = TabSection2.new(self, self)
        yield(ts)
        render :partial => '/tab2', locals: {section: ts}
      end
```

The partial renders the output of the tabs render function:

```
    %ul
      - section.tabs.each do |tab|
        %li= tab.name
    .content
      - section.tabs.each do |tab|
        .tab
          = tab.render.html_safe
```

Which is implemented as follows:

```
    class Tab2

      attr_reader :name, :blk
      def initialize(name, context, &blk)
        @context = context
        @name = name
        @blk = blk 
      end 

      def render
        @context.capture_haml(&@blk)
      end 
    end 

    class TabSection2
      attr_reader :tabs

      def initialize(context)
        @context = context
        @tabs = []
      end 

      def tab(name, &blk)
        raise "Y U NO SUPPLY block?" unless block_given?
        @tabs << Tab2.new(name, @context, &blk)
      end 
    end
```